# Java NIO causes file descriptor leak

Tags: java, ubuntu, memory-leaks, nio

We have a http server which is implemented based on Java NIO.
It is running on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS with java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

However, it leaks file descriptors, all of them are unix domain sockets.

When use the command "netstat -anp", we can find that the process only opens two unix domain socket.
However, when use lsof -p , we can find that there are huge amounts of file descriptors which are unix domain socket and have the same device value and node value as the one find in netstat.

I have checked our code, and all of the SocketChannels are closed properly.

Is it a bug of Sun JDK?
How can we fix it?

Comment: Have you tried Java 6 update 26? If it is a JVM bug, it is possible it has been fixed which would show it was a bug.

Comment: @James Which NIO API are you using to use Java with Unix Domain Sockets? Are you using some specific API like XNIO? I am looking to find something that works with Unix Domain Sockets and NIO. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is found.
In our code, when we close socketchannel, we also cancel the key. The problem is that:
a. We cancel the key in the select thread, and close the socketchannel in another thread
b. The socket channel is closed until the key.cancel is invoked.

By reading the implementation of close and cancel, we can find that the unix domain socket is opened by dup2 and never closed some times (concurrent issue).

Comment: Closing the channel cancels the key: you don't need to cancel it yourself as well. I don't know what 'The socket channel is closed until the key.cancel is invoked' is intended to mean but as stated it is false. What actually happens is that the channel *isnt'* actually closed until next time the selector runs.

Comment: If following code is executed in a thread other than the selector thread, it will also have problem.
`selectionKey.cancel();
socketChannel.close();`

In our code, it is a bit different. selectionKey.cancel is called in selector thread, and it notifies another thread to call `socketChannel.close();`. It has the concurrent issue too, since the key is canceled actually at next select.

Comment: Hi EJP, the problem we encountered is that even next time the selector runs, the unix domain socket is not closed, because of the concurrent issue. Actually, the unix domain socket won't have a chance to closed if the concurrent issue occurs.

Comment: 'In our code, it is a bit different. selectionKey.cancel is called in selector thread, and it notifies another thread to call socketChannel.close();' Why? Why not just close the channel in the selector thread? It's not much use after you've cancelled the key. As to the previous reply, you can collapse that to socketChannel.close() and it will execute identically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Selectors use Unix domain sockets. Are you closing them?

Comment: We only create one Selector instance and never close it.